# evaluate $(1+xy)ydx+(1-xy)xdy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(1+xy)ydx+(1-xy)xdy=0$$
We can evaluate the following DE by using exact DE method .
we can write it as $$d(xy) +xy^3\frac{(ydx-xdy)}{y^2}=0$$
on  malupulating further we get
$$\frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2} +\frac{y}{x}d(\frac{x}{y})=0$$
On integrating we get $$\frac{-1}{xy} +log(\frac{x}{y})=c$$

But on closely observing we can see that there are 2 more solutions to this DE which are not included in general solutions .
They are,

1)x=0

2)y=0

Why they are missing from general solution .What kind of solutions will $x=0$ and $y=0$ be called ? General solution , particular solution or singular solution ?

Comment: By "evaluate" the DE do you mean "solve" instead?

Comment: Anyway, note that you have divided by $(xy)^2$ in this process, hence you lost $xy=0$.3

Comment: @EverywhereDense corrected it

Comment: @user10354138 , but we dont care about domain while solving DE right ? (yeah evaluating and solving means the same )

Comment: You should care.  Otherwise why not divide by $0$ and declare it solved (with domain $\varnothing$)?

Comment: @user10354138 ok i understand but , symbolab math solver gives the same ans (i.e doesnt include x =0 and y=0 in solution ) https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(1%2Bxy%5Cright)ydx%2B%5Cleft(1%E2%88%92xy%5Cright)xdy%3D0?or=input

Comment: @user10354138 also while solving DE sometimes we take sin^-1 of both sides even without caring about principal value branch . This is a very big mistake .We are ignoring various solutions but if you make any one solve this DE sin(dy/dx) =x , even calculators will take $sin^{-1}$ of both sides

Comment: @user10354138  Whereas if you make anyone solve $(y')^2$=(x+1)^2$  all of them will find 2 solutions . y'=x+1 and y'=-x-1